# How to disable windows' contents being moved on dragging, so that only the frame is dragged and the whole window is only redrawn on drop?

Tags: gnome, metacity

How to disable windows' contents being moved on dragging, so that only the frame is dragged and the whole window is only redrawn on drop?

In Windows, KDE and XFCE this can be easily configured, but in Gnome (Ubuntu 10.10) I couldn't find where to set this up :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, disable desktop effects to get metacity instead of compiz.  Then open gconf-editor, find `/apps/metacity/general`, and enable `reduced_resources`.  Here's a description of that option:

> If true, metacity will give the user less feedback by using wireframes, avoiding animations, or other means. This is a significant reduction in usability for many users, but may allow legacy applications to continue working, and may also be a useful tradeoff for terminal servers. However, the wireframe feature is disabled when accessibility is on.

As far as I know there's no option to enable it through the GUI, gconf is the only way.