# Making window moves/drags as wireframes in LXDE?

Tags: lubuntu, window-manager, lxde, openbox

I'm using x2go for remote desktop management over a relatively high latency link, using Windows and Linux clients, and the host/server is Lubuntu 14.04.

I've managed to optimize most of the settings, but one thing that is horribly slow is when I drag a window (especially a browser window) there's a noticeable lag/delay.

I recall from my fvwm2 days (I know, I know...) there was an option where you could tell the window manager to only show the wireframe of a window when it was being moved or resized, instead of constantly repainting the entire window contents.

Is there a way to set this behavior in LXDE?  I suppose a more accurate question might be "is there a way to do this in openbox"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable windows' contents to be moved on dragging, so that only a frame is draggend and a window is obly redrawed on drop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5161/how-to-disable-windows-contents-to-be-moved-on-dragging-so-that-only-a-frame-i)

Comment: That answer is for compiz/gnome, which isn't the environment I'm asking about here...

Comment: I'm curious, what other settings have you optimized in Lubuntu for remote desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem using xrdp. There doesn't seem to be any effort to implement this function in openbox (see https://bugzilla.icculus.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3342 ). However, there is the possibility to use an alternative window manager with LXDE (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Use_a_different_window_manager -> option: "window_manager=" ), which then offers this function (in my case, JWM helped -> option: MoveMode and ResizeMode in .jwmrc). Fluxbox will also work.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `drawContent` option in `/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml` or its homedir equivalent:

```
sed -i -e "s%<drawContents>yes</drawContents>%<drawContents>no</drawContents>%" /etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml
```

Log out and in again (or just restart openbox) and now dragging only displays the frame.

This is working for me in Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04. Haven't tried other releases.

Comment: Found <DrawContent> only once in the file you mentioned. It is in <resize></resize> section. 
So tested it and it is NOT for moving windows but JUST for resizing windows in their size. 
Unfortunately not the answer to the question.

Comment: @linolino From the [openbox docs](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration#Resize_.28and_move.29), this section applies to resize and move. As stated on my last paragraph, I did test this setting on trusty and xenial and it works. What version are you using?

Comment: just installed an Lubuntu 16.04 LTS in a VirtualBox. Thought moving a window should just move frame and not total content in a lean OS but couldn't find something. Killed a Xubuntu installation... for Xubuntu I got davise how to get it fixed in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/574024/how-to-disable-windows-contents-to-be-moved-on-dragging-so-that-only-a-frame-i

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of a wireframe option but openbox does allow lots of custom window management through keyboard shortcuts. However http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Configuration suggests that if you edit ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml if you are using the lubuntu session. 
  no
  Always
  Fixed
  
    400
    center
  
 editing the line that says draw contents to no will make it a solid color when moving and resizing windows. To get openbox to reload its configuratoin file you will need to run `openbox --reconfigure`

If this still does not perform well enough you can try to work around resizing windows with the mouse with the following methods. Although out of the box lubuntu has keyboard shortcuts to snap windows to half the screens size with the super (windows key) and an arrow key to snap to that half of the screen. Also keep in mind you can learn to use virtual workspaces in lubuntu and switch between those in lubuntu to aviod needing to resize windows as often. There are the keyboard shortcuts control alt left and control alt right to switch between desktops. You can also use the windows key and f1 or f2 but you can add up to four workspaces and then super key plus f3 and f4 will allow you to switch to additional workspaces. You can add works spaces just for this session by middle clicking on the desktop or permanently by setting a number in openbox configuration manager.

Comment: The option you quoted only affects resizing. Did you actually try it before answering? None of your the remainder of your answer addresses moving either. The whole thing is almost completely irrelevant to the question that was asked.